# How to handle Reminder that are old and new for windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

say, this is the way to create reminder:

```
 Reminder reminder = new Reminder(name);
            reminder.Title = titleTextBox.Text;
            reminder.Content = contentTextBox.Text;
            reminder.BeginTime = beginTime;
            reminder.ExpirationTime = expirationTime;
            reminder.RecurrenceType = recurrence;
            reminder.NavigationUri = navigationUri;

            // Register the reminder with the system.
            ScheduledActionService.Add(reminder);
```

I can not see the result as I use emulator and I have these questions:

1) If I create a reminder today 25/Jul : Begin time 25-jul and ExpirationTime : 25-jul, after 25-jul, will the reminder created on 25-jul will still be in the system or scheduler?

2) If the expirationTime is 28-Jul, will it shows the BeginTime when this reminder got activated on 28-jul?

3) How to I retrieve all the reminders have not be activated.

Thanks

--- Updated :

```
var reminders = ScheduledActionService.GetActions (ScheduledAction)();     
                  .Where(a => a.IsScheduled);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Yes, it will be there. Reminders associated with an application are still available, even if those are dismissed by the user.

2) The **BeginTime** will be set according to the class property that is set by the application, not when the reminder was activated.

3) You can retrieve all reminders registered for your application through:

```
var n = ScheduledActionService.GetActions<Reminder>();
foreach (Reminder r in n)
  // Action here
```

You can check the `IsScheduled` property to make sure that the reminder is scheduled to be triggered or is already out of the queue.

Comment: Thank you. For Question(1), Is that means we need to delete the reminders ourselves since old reminders will not get fired anyway. How to do it?

Comment: There is `ScheduledActionService.Remove` for that (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.scheduledactionservice.remove%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Comment: For question(1): It seems all the reminders have been fired will not be retrieved when use abouve code. Ie: create a reminder on 26-7-2011. after it is fired up, it will not be shown in above code. This means the scheduler will "AUTO delete"? I test this in emulator.

Comment: The event `IsScheduled` property will be set to `False`, but you still should be able to retrieve it.